# PHP preg_replace expression for following requirement?

Tags: php, regex

Input text:

```
 Hello, raj's            dogs age                              is 18. "
```

Output:

```
Hello, raj's dogs age is 18.
```

Requirements:

1. Remove Extra space between words.
2. allow Capital & Small letter & number & dot(.) & single quotes(').
3. Do Not allow space at starting and ending of string.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace multiples spaces with one space.

```
echo trim(preg_replace('/\h+/', ' ', ' Hello, raj\'s           dogs age                     is 18. '));
```

The `\h` is a horizontal whitespace (tab/space). The `+` after means at least one must be preset. The space in the replacement replaces the one or more with just one. PHP's `trim` can then be used to remove leading/trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

use str_replace() function

```
$string = " Hello, raj's           dogs age                     is 18. ";
$result=str_replace(' ', ' ', $string);
echo $result;
```

Comment: What are you doing here? This replaces a space with a space, that doesn't fix any of the issues. (e.g. if you run the code https://3v4l.org/L6l0d)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing *two* or more whitespace characters with just a single space:

```
$string = " Hello, raj's           dogs age                     is 18. ";
$result = trim(preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $string));
echo $result;
```

This prints:

```
Hello, raj's dogs age is 18.
```